# Find files where prefix and suffix match

Tags: linux, bash, find

I would like to find all files where the first part of the filename (up to the first `.`) matches the file extension (after the last `.`).

For example, the following files would match:

```
cat.cat
cat.txt.cat
```

Whereas `cat.txt.asm` would not.

How can I do this using `find`?

Comment: Yes. You should use find for this. But your question is written in a much confusing way.

Comment: Please give us Input and Output if english isn't your first language.

Comment: Ok, sorry, once again. To the script i give one argument which is directory tree. Then it should iterate through all its files and Look for those which one of extensions (after dot) is the same as its name before this dot - filename.filename

Comment: You can use [`find -regex`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and study https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression to learn how to form proper regex.

Comment: ./script directory  /// result = file.file, txt.txt, hello.hello.. etc

Comment: I have rephrased your question - hopefully I haven't misinterpreted what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use the -regex option to `find`:

```
find -regex '.*/\([^.]+\)\.\(.*\.\)?\1'
```

- `.*/` matches the path to the file
- `\([^.]+\)` captures anything up to the first dot (`+` means at least one character)
- `\(.*\.\)?` matches the middle part, i.e. anything ending in a dot, but the whole thing is optional
- `\1` means the first capture is repeated

Might be more readable in the egrep dialect:

```
find -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([^.]+)\.(.*\.)?\1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    find . -type f -iname "*" | awk -F/ '{print $2}' |awk -F. '$1==$NF'

Or

    ls -1 | awk -F. '$1==$NF'
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry this is better:

You could just simply do this:

for exemple find toto.tata.toto specific:

```
find . -regex ".*\(toto\)[^\/]*\.\1"
```

Generic:

```
find . -regex ".*/\([^./\]*\)[^\/]*\.\1"
```

Comment: The regexp is wrong. It will not match the right files and it will not match all of them.